# Invert two strings inside brackets

Tags: regex, database, sas

I have a `coordinates` column that refers to an ID with 3 dimensions `[z][x][y]`. What I am trying to do is to invert the `[x]` dimension with the `[y]` so that it becomes a table with (still) 3 dimensions but ordered differently: `[z][y][x]`
Here is a snippet of the column:

```
    +------------------------+
    |     COORDINATES        |
    +------------------------+
    | ID_01.02.a[][01][20]   |
    | ID_02.00[010][02][017] |
    | ID_03.01[][][010]      |
    | ID_04.01.w[010][][]    |
    +------------------------+
```

Here is the code to reproduce this snippet:

```
    data have;
    input coordinates :$30.;
    datalines;
    ID_01.02.a[][01][20]
    ID_02.00[010][02][017]
    ID_03.01[][][010]
    ID_04.01.w[010][][]
    ;
```

The final table is expected to be:

```
    +------------------------+
    |     COORDINATES        |
    +------------------------+
    | ID_01.02.a[][20][01]   |
    | ID_02.00[010][017][02] |
    | ID_03.01[][010][]      |
    | ID_04.01.w[010][][]    |
    +------------------------+
```

When I tried using the scan function, it did not work because I could not find a robust index e.g. `x_after = trim(scan(coordinates,2,'[]'))`. Indeed, if the z axis is not empty it will output the z axis and if the z axis is empty, it will output the x axis.

Comment: with a little change, you can still use your program: `x_after = trim(scan(tranwrd(coordinates,'[]','[ ]'),2,'[]'))`.

Comment: Does anyone know why SO is showing every other line of the data in this question with slanted font?  Why is it even looking for formatting clues in data blocks?

Comment: I think it has to do with a language syntax processing (still digging).  The funny portions are spans with class `hljs-*`.  While digging I found that HTML TABLES are now supported! https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support?cb=1

Comment: Talk about italics after underscore in meta.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402864/code-block-is-rendered-incorrectly-partially-in-italic-after-underscore/402865#402865

Comment: The work around appears to be to specify none as the code language `\`\`\`none`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with SCAN().  Use `[]` as the delimiters and the `m` modifier. But now your strings have 6 values and not 4 as there are empty values between the places with `][` .

Here is a way that shows what is happening.

```
data have;
  input COORDINATES $50.;
cards;
ID_01.02.a[][01][20]
ID_02.00[010][02][017]
ID_03.01[][][010]
ID_04.01.w[010][][]
;

data want;
  set have;
  length want $50;
  array temp[6] $50;
  do i=1 to dim(temp);
    temp[i]=scan(coordinates,i,'[]','m');
  end;
  want = cats(temp[1],'[',temp[2],'][',temp[6],'][',temp[4],']');
  drop i;
run;
```

Results:

```
Obs        COORDINATES                  want              temp1      temp2   temp3   temp4   temp5   temp6

 1    ID_01.02.a[][01][20]     ID_01.02.a[][20][01]     ID_01.02.a                    01              20
 2    ID_02.00[010][02][017]   ID_02.00[010][017][02]   ID_02.00      010             02              017
 3    ID_03.01[][][010]        ID_03.01[][010][]        ID_03.01                                      010
 4    ID_04.01.w[010][][]      ID_04.01.w[010][][]      ID_04.01.w    010
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access regular expression power via `PRXCHANGE` to modify values containing both simple and complex patterns.

Example:

```
data have;
  input COORDINATES $char50.;
  datalines;
  ID_01.02.a[][01][20]   
  ID_02.00[010][02][017] 
  ID_03.01[][][010]      
  ID_04.01.w[010][][]    
;

data want;
  set have;

  put coordinates;
  coordinates = prxchange
    ( 's/(.*?\[.*?\])(\[.*?\])(\[.*\])/$1$3$2/'
    , 1
    , coordinates
    );

  put coordinates /;
run;
```

Logs

```
ID_01.02.a[][01][20]
ID_01.02.a[][20][01]

ID_02.00[010][02][017]
ID_02.00[010][017][02]

ID_03.01[][][010]
ID_03.01[][010][]

ID_04.01.w[010][][]
ID_04.01.w[010][][]
```